# What is an easy way to call Asc() and Chr() in JavaScript for Unicode values?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am not that familiar with Javascript, and am looking for the function that returns the UNICODE value of a character, and given the UNICODE value, returns the string equivalent. I'm sure there is something simple, but I don't see it.

Example:

- ASC("A") = 65
- CHR(65) = "A"
- ASC("ਔ") = 2580
- CHR(2580) = "ਔ"

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be asc() but uni(). Ha ha, I'm in fine form this morning :-).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
String.fromCharCode(64)
```

and

```
String.prototype.charCodeAt(0)
```

The first must be called on the String **class** (literally `String.fromCharCode...`) and will return "@" (for 64). The second should be run on a String **instance** or **primitive** (e.g., `"@@@".charCodeAt...`) and returns the Unicode code of the first character (the '0' is a position within the string, you can get the codes for other characters in the string by changing that to another number).

The script snippet:

```
document.write("Unicode for character ਔ is: " + "ਔ".charCodeAt(0) + "<br />");
document.write("Character 2580 is " + String.fromCharCode(2580) + "<br />");
```

gives:

```
Unicode for character ਔ is: 2580
Character 2580 is ਔ
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the function I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Because [JavaScript uses UCS-2 internally](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding), `String.fromCharCode(codePoint)` won’t work for supplementary Unicode characters. If `codePoint` is `119558` (`0x1D306`, for the `''` character), for example.

If you want to create a string based on a non-BMP Unicode code point, you could use [Punycode.js](http://mths.be/punycode)’s utility functions to convert between UCS-2 strings and UTF-16 code points:

```
// `String.fromCharCode` replacement that doesn’t make you enter the surrogate halves separately
punycode.ucs2.encode([0x1d306]); // ''
punycode.ucs2.encode([119558]); // ''
punycode.ucs2.encode([97, 98, 99]); // 'abc'
```

if you want to get the Unicode code point for every character in a string, you’ll need to convert the UCS-2 string into an array of UTF-16 code points (where each surrogate pair forms a single code point). You could use [Punycode.js](http://mths.be/punycode)’s utility functions for this:

```
punycode.ucs2.decode('abc'); // [97, 98, 99]
punycode.ucs2.decode(''); // [119558]
```

Comment: Actually, Javascript uses UTF-16 Encoding. If you put more than the BMP into it, and read it you will get exactly the same out as you put in. Though you wont be writing a word processor in it.

Comment: I read your article, and it browser dependent. Thus if you shove UTF-16 encoding into v8 Chrome JavaScript, you get exactly the unicode code points out. The rendering of such codepoints are a different story.

Comment: @Chad None of it is browser-dependent. The article is about how ECMAScript engines are supposed to expose “characters” according to the spec, and all engines I know of do this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Example for generating alphabet array here :

```
const arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i< 20; i++) {
    arr.push( String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i) )
}
```